# heroku deployment fail - Can't resolve scss

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass, next.js

When I deploy the application in Heroku
Below error throws

```
Failed to compile.
./pages/index.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/styles/Home.module.scss' in '/tmp/build_2e86dc1e/pages'
> Build failed because of webpack errors
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
```

But I've already tried to build it on local by running `next build` and it's successful

**Update 1**

Provided the folder strucuture
[image]

Comment: I think Heroku strips anything in `devDependencies` after the build, but right before deployment. Are you using anything related to Sass in a `heroku-postbuild` script?

Comment: @Mark G I don't have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed that.

The reason is I'm importing the `home.module.scss` with a capital H. And heroku is case sensitive on imports.

Heroku uses Linux, which cares about the difference between `home.module.scss` and `Home.module.scss`